# Integrating apache ignite in legacy java sql based project joins issue

Tags: sql, join, persistence, ignite

I have a legacy java project where I have more than 1000 table and a lot of SQL queries.

In order to achieve a better querying performance I m studying the apache ignite in memory database where I wan't to use the 3rd party persistence mechanism, the later is based on caching (CacheStore) that  I implemented successfully in my POC, unfortunately I have lot of complex queries with lot of joins, in this case I have to update my queries using cache store names as in the example

```
    private static void select(IgniteCache<Long, Person> personCache, String msg) {
        String sql =
            "select p.id, concat(p.firstName, ' ', p.lastName), o.name, p.resume, p.salary " +
            "from Person as p, \"" + ORG_CACHE + "\".Organization as o " +
            "where p.orgId = o.id";

        List<List<?>> res = personCache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(sql).setDistributedJoins(true)).getAll();

        print(msg);

        for (Object next : res)
            System.out.println(">>>     " + next);
    }
```

I really wish to avoid this, and use native SQL.

Is there any other possible solutions to achieve joins using the 3rd party persistence and cache

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a cache, you can set its `sqlSchema` to `"PUBLIC"`. If you do that for all caches, you will never need to specify their schemas explicitly (if that's what your question was about).

Comment: so ORG_CACHE is the schema name ??

Comment: Yes. It is by default identical to cache name, though.

Comment: I m trying to figure out alone how to set the schema public but I can't found how using web console please provide ;ore detail how to

Comment: You can do that when creating your cache via code (`cacheConfiguration.setSqlSchema()`). Once cache is created you can't change cache schema.