# apache ignite loading cache ClassCastException

Tags: java, ignite

I m trying to use apache ignite, I m generating my node using the ignite web console.

I needed to configure 2 caches from database and enabled the persistence storage since the two table have lot of data.

Here is what I have done (the console)

```
    /**
     * Configure grid.
     * 
     * @return Ignite configuration.
     * @throws Exception If failed to construct Ignite configuration instance.
     **/
    public static IgniteConfiguration createConfiguration() throws Exception {
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        cfg.setClientMode(true);
        cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("attiryak");

        TcpDiscoverySpi discovery = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();

        ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47510"));

        discovery.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discovery);

        AtomicConfiguration atomicCfg = new AtomicConfiguration();

        atomicCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL);

        cfg.setAtomicConfiguration(atomicCfg);

        DataStorageConfiguration dataStorageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();

        dataStorageCfg.setPageSize(16384);
        dataStorageCfg.setConcurrencyLevel(2);
        dataStorageCfg.setSystemRegionInitialSize(52428800L);
        dataStorageCfg.setSystemRegionMaxSize(209715200L);

        DataRegionConfiguration dataRegionCfg = new DataRegionConfiguration();

        dataRegionCfg.setInitialSize(536870912L);
        dataRegionCfg.setMaxSize(1073741824L);
        dataRegionCfg.setMetricsEnabled(true);
        dataRegionCfg.setPersistenceEnabled(true);

        dataStorageCfg.setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(dataRegionCfg);

        cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(dataStorageCfg);

        cfg.setCacheConfiguration(
            cacheMInoutlineCache(),
            cacheMInoutlineconfirmCache()
        );

        return cfg;
    }
```

```
    public static CacheConfiguration cacheMInoutlineCache() throws Exception {
        CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration();

        ccfg.setName("MInoutlineCache");
        ccfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL);
        ccfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
        ccfg.setCopyOnRead(true);

        CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory cacheStoreFactory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory();

        cacheStoreFactory.setDataSourceFactory(new Factory<DataSource>() {
            /** {@inheritDoc} **/
            @Override public DataSource create() {
                return DataSources.INSTANCE_dsOracle_Compiere;
            };
        });

        cacheStoreFactory.setDialect(new OracleDialect());

        cacheStoreFactory.setTypes(jdbcTypeMInoutline(ccfg.getName()));

        ccfg.setCacheStoreFactory(cacheStoreFactory);

        ccfg.setReadThrough(true);
        ccfg.setWriteThrough(true);

        ArrayList<QueryEntity> qryEntities = new ArrayList<>();

        QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity();

        qryEntity.setKeyType("java.lang.Long");
        qryEntity.setValueType("com.gmail.talcorpdz.model.MInoutline");
        qryEntity.setTableName("M_INOUTLINE");
        qryEntity.setKeyFieldName("mInoutlineId");

        HashSet<String> keyFields = new HashSet<>();

        keyFields.add("mInoutlineId");

        qryEntity.setKeyFields(keyFields);

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        fields.put("adClientId", "java.lang.Long");

        qryEntity.setFields(fields);

        HashMap<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<>();

        aliases.put("mInoutlineId", "M_INOUTLINE_ID");
        qryEntity.setAliases(aliases);

        ArrayList<QueryIndex> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

        QueryIndex index = new QueryIndex();

        index.setName("IDX$$_00010002");
        index.setIndexType(QueryIndexType.SORTED);

        LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean> indFlds = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        indFlds.put("mAttributesetinstanceId", false);
        indFlds.put("mInoutId", false);
        qryEntity.setIndexes(indexes);
        qryEntities.add(qryEntity);

        ccfg.setQueryEntities(qryEntities);

        /**
         * @author taleb 
         * 
         * spec 1.0 : no schema needed solution
         * https://stackoverflow.com/a/58930331/4388228
         * */
        ccfg.setSqlSchema("PUBLIC");

        return ccfg;
    }
```

I believe that I m miss configuring my storage since it is mandatory to help memory to use my disk space.

Here is the stack trace of the exception

> ```
> [11:49:58]    __________  ________________ 
> [11:49:58]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/ 
> [11:49:58]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/   
> [11:49:58] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/  
> [11:49:58] 
> [11:49:58] ver. 2.7.6#20190911-sha1:21f7ca41
> [11:49:58] 2019 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
> [11:49:58] 
> [11:49:58] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
> [11:49:58] 
> [11:49:58] Quiet mode.
> [11:49:58]   ^-- Logging by 'JavaLogger [quiet=true, config=null]'
> [11:49:58]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
> [11:49:58] 
> [11:49:58] OS: Linux 4.19.0-kali5-amd64 amd64
> [11:49:58] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_201-b09 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.201-b09
> [11:49:58] Please set system property '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to avoid possible problems in mixed environments.
> [11:49:58] Initial heap size is 124MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
> [11:49:58] Configured plugins:
> [11:49:58]   ^-- None
> [11:49:58] 
> [11:49:58] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
> [11:49:59] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
> [11:49:59] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
> [11:49:59] REST protocols do not start on client node. To start the protocols on client node set '-DIGNITE_REST_START_ON_CLIENT=true' system property.
> [11:50:00] Nodes started on local machine require more than 80% of physical RAM what can lead to significant slowdown due to swapping (please decrease JVM heap size, data region size or checkpoint buffer size) [required=4979MB, available=7867MB]
> [11:50:00] Performance suggestions for grid 'attiryak' (fix if possible)
> [11:50:00] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
> [11:50:00]   ^-- Enable G1 Garbage Collector (add '-XX:+UseG1GC' to JVM options)
> [11:50:00]   ^-- Specify JVM heap max size (add '-Xmx<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
> [11:50:00]   ^-- Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
> [11:50:00]   ^-- Disable processing of calls to System.gc() (add '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC' to JVM options)
> [11:50:00] Refer to this page for more performance suggestions: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning
> [11:50:00] 
> [11:50:00] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
> [11:50:00] Data Regions Configured:
> [11:50:00]   ^-- default [initSize=512.0 MiB, maxSize=1.0 GiB, persistence=true]
> [11:50:00] 
> [11:50:00] Ignite node started OK (id=7ad24962, instance name=attiryak)
> [11:50:00] >>> Ignite cluster is not active (limited functionality available). Use control.(sh|bat) script or IgniteCluster interface to activate.
> [11:50:00] Topology snapshot [ver=2, locNode=7ad24962, servers=1, clients=1, state=INACTIVE, CPUs=8, offheap=2.0GB, heap=3.4GB]
> >> Loading caches...
> Nov 19, 2019 11:50:01 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
> SEVERE: Failed to activate node components [nodeId=7ad24962-e5c8-4f0b-8b99-1c42a3c91c01, client=true, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=1]]
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.ignite.internal.pagemem.impl.PageMemoryNoStoreImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.pagemem.PageMemoryEx
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheOffheapManager.getOrAllocateCacheMetas(GridCacheOffheapManager.java:728)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheOffheapManager.initDataStructures(GridCacheOffheapManager.java:123)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.start(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:196)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheGroupContext.start(CacheGroupContext.java:937)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCacheGroup(GridCacheProcessor.java:2251)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:2146)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.processCacheStartRequests(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:898)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.onCacheChangeRequest(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:798)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onClusterStateChangeRequest(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1114)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:736)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2681)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2553)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> >> Loading cache: MInoutlineCache
> Nov 19, 2019 11:50:02 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
> SEVERE: Failed to process custom exchange task: ClientCacheChangeDummyDiscoveryMessage [reqId=587e6edb-95ee-4208-a525-a35ca441bf7c, cachesToClose=null, startCaches=[MInoutlineCache]]
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.ignite.internal.pagemem.impl.PageMemoryNoStoreImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.pagemem.PageMemoryEx
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheOffheapManager.getOrAllocateCacheMetas(GridCacheOffheapManager.java:728)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheOffheapManager.initDataStructures(GridCacheOffheapManager.java:123)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.start(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:196)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheGroupContext.start(CacheGroupContext.java:937)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCacheGroup(GridCacheProcessor.java:2251)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:2146)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.processClientCacheStartRequests(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:438)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.processClientCachesChanges(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:637)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.processCustomExchangeTask(GridCacheProcessor.java:391)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.processCustomTask(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2489)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2634)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2553)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> ```

what should I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and it stems from the fact that previously you started the same cluster but without persistence.

Please remove your Ignite work dir (%TMP%\ignite\work or /tmp/ignite/work or ./ignite/work) and restart your node.

UPD: There is also this issue about LOCAL cache on client node with persistence: [IGNITE-11677](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-11677). My recommendation is to avoid using LOCAL caches at all.

Comment: I m using a linux distribution I removed work from my project folder and from ingite_home folder but the same issue, I even cleaned the project target but no success

Comment: Are you using package-installed Ignite?

Comment: issue is in local cache Thanks I m new to ignite (first day) I Appreciate your help.